# Make Node's "forever" log to syslog

Tags: node.js, syslog

I'm creating a small server using Node.js that I want to keep running with [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever). Forever generates three logfiles: my apps STDOUT, STDERR and the log of forever itself.

Is there a way to make forever log to syslog instead of to logfiles? Either using forever from the commandline or using its API?

Comment: Ask on here http://unix.stackexchange.com/ I know that you can just bash script that around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Up https://github.com/LearnBoost/up and use the Unix API to log...

Answer (score 1):

```
forever start -a -o >(logger -t appname) -e >(logger -t appname) app.js
```